# what is proxy server

Tags: sharepoint, proxy

What is proxy server exactly. What its purpose ?

Comment: You spelt exactly wrong.

Comment: Then what it should be ?

Comment: see here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263524%28office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two types of [firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)):  packet filters and proxies.

A proxy can have many purposes.  Essentially it's a gateway that can restrict and/or log network accesses.

Maybe you're the admin of a network and you want to monitor the web traffic being accessed by company employees.

In that case you might have your client computers configured such that their web browsers / other apps are configured to access the internet through the proxy.

The proxy can then log what is being accessed - and by whom.

Proxies like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) specialise in caching frequently accessed network resources, in order to reduce bandwidth consumption.

There are many other uses, these are just a few.  Hope this helps!